# problem when authenticating in telegram with kotlogram in android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, telegram

I'm confused to log into my telegram account using the kotlogram library on android, I manage to get a confirmation code, but then an error occurs
error in try block:

```
2022-03-22 09:47:29.539 27694-27900/com.example.mailings
W/System.err: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.github.badoualy.telegram.mtproto.MTProtoWatchdog@a412131 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@2be4016[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1] 2022-03-22 09:47:29.539 27694-27900/com.example.mailings
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2086) 2022-03-22 09:47:29.539 27694-27900/com.example.mailings 
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:848) 2022-03-22 09:47:29.539 27694-27900/com.example.mailings
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1394) 2022-03-22 09:47:29.539 27694-27900/com.example.mailings
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute(Executors.java:630) 2022-03-22 09:47:29.540 27694-27900/com.example.mailings
W/System.err:     at com.github.badoualy.telegram.mtproto.MTProtoWatchdog$start$1.call(MTProtoWatchdog.kt:121) 2022-03-22 09:47:29.540 27694-27900/com.example.mailings
W/System.err:     at com.github.badoualy.telegram.mtproto.MTProtoWatchdog$start$1.call(MTProtoWatchdog.kt:112)
```

then the app crashes:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread. Add `onError` handling.
         at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:57)
         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Task com.github.badoualy.telegram.mtproto.MTProtoWatchdog@a412131 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@2be4016[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
         at rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils$ErrorNotImplementedAction.call(InternalObservableUtils.java:386)
         at rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils$ErrorNotImplementedAction.call(InternalObservableUtils.java:383)
         at rx.internal.util.ActionSubscriber.onError(ActionSubscriber.java:44)
         at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:152)
         at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:115)
         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87)
         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87)
         at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:276)
         at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:219)
         at rx.internal.schedulers.EventLoopsScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(EventLoopsScheduler.java:172)
         at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.github.badoualy.telegram.mtproto.MTProtoWatchdog@a412131 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@2be4016[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2086)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:848)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1394)
         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute(Executors.java:630)
         at com.github.badoualy.telegram.mtproto.MTProtoWatchdog$start$1.call(MTProtoWatchdog.kt:121)
         at com.github.badoualy.telegram.mtproto.MTProtoWatchdog$start$1.call(MTProtoWatchdog.kt:112)
         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
         at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)         
         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
         at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
         at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10247)
         at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10214)
         at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:9989)
         at com.github.badoualy.telegram.mtproto.MTProtoHandler.startWatchdog(MTProtoHandler.kt:91)
         at com.github.badoualy.telegram.mtproto.MTProtoHandler.resetConnection(MTProtoHandler.kt:106)
         at com.github.badoualy.telegram.api.DefaultTelegramClient.executeRpcQueries(DefaultTelegramClient.kt:252)
         at com.github.badoualy.telegram.api.DefaultTelegramClient.executeRpcQueries$default(DefaultTelegramClient.kt:215) 2022-03-22 09:47:29.544 27694-27900/com.example.mailings E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.github.badoualy.telegram.api.DefaultTelegramClient.executeRpcQueries(DefaultTelegramClient.kt:193)
         at com.github.badoualy.telegram.api.TelegramClient$DefaultImpls.executeRpcQuery(TelegramClient.kt:57)
         at com.github.badoualy.telegram.api.DefaultTelegramClient.executeRpcQuery(DefaultTelegramClient.kt:189)
         at com.github.badoualy.telegram.tl.api.TelegramApiWrapper.authSignIn(TelegramApiWrapper.java:301)
         at com.example.mailings.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-8$lambda-7$lambda-3$lambda-2(MainActivity.kt:64)
         at com.example.mailings.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$7dTpC36H6j2r2RgiVFs9_kQQ6dA(Unknown Source:0)
         at com.example.mailings.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda8.run(Unknown Source:8)
```

MainActivity at 64:

```
val authorization: TLAuthorization = client.authSignIn(PHONE_NUMBER, sentCode.phoneCodeHash, code)
```

I also had a question, is it possible in principle to use kotlogram in android?

I added the entire authorization process to a separate thread and added permissions to use memory and the Internet to the manifest. I used tricks from kotlogram documentation

Answer (score 0):

the problem for me was the "client.close" command, removing it I don't get the problem anymore